# jsTree is not displaying properly in Internet Explorer 9. Works in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jstree

When viewing my tree in Internet Explorer 9 my jsTree is not displaying properly. My tree looks fine when viewed in Firefox and Safari. If I just display my tree as a Unordered List (ul) in IE9, it shows fine. But as soon as I make it a jsTree it messes up again.

This is what my tree looks like in Firefox with all of its nodes collapsed:

> 00012 TestNetwork_4
>   00013 WACK

This is what my tree looks like in Internet Explorer:

> 00012 TestNetwork_4
>   02 RFSS_2
>   group

Here are the plugins that I'm using:

```
plugins : ["themes", "html_data", "types", "ui", "cookies"]
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?